# dialog will not close after the second time it is opened

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why won't this dialog close on the second time its opened.

The first time I click the button then it opens, then 3 seconds later it closes....perfect.

BUT

the second time I click to open it, it opens but won't close

If I use destroy to close then I get an error saying

Error: Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

script

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
       var o = function (tt, ii) {
            $('<div>', {
                'text': tt,
                'id': ii
            }).dialog();
        };
        var c = function (ii) {
            $('#' + ii).dialog('close');
        };
        var magic = function () {
           o('my string', 'x');
            setTimeout(function () {
                c('x');
            }, 3000);
        };
        magic();
    });
});
```

Comment: You are creating several `<div>` elements with the same id, but `id` attributes must be unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating multiple elements with the same id

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var $dialog = $('<div />');
        var o = function (tt) {
            $dialog.text(tt).dialog({
                close: function(){
                    $dialog.remove();
                }
            });
        };
        var c = function () {
            $dialog.dialog('close');
        };
        var magic = function () {
            o('my string', 'x');
            setTimeout(function () {
                c('x');
            }, 3000);
        };
        magic();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y3f7C/)

Comment: thanks . do you know how I would do it with the ID i need it as I will be adding loads? thanks

Comment: @Hello-World just remove the element once the dialog is closed